# Prevent Sql Server sending Failover partner to connecting clients

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring, failover

I have 2 Sql Server 2008R2, enterprise edition servers setup in an asynchronous (High Peformance) mirror setup. There is no witness.

Intermittently I find that a client will attempt to connect to the secondary instead of the primary.  This is despite the fact that the connection string used has no reference to a failover partner.

My research led me to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/database-mirroring-in-sql-server, which states

> "When a SqlConnection is successfully opened, the failover partner
> name is returned by the server and supersedes any values supplied in
> the connection string."

I believe this is the reason I'm getting spurious connections to the secondary mirror server.

My question is this: I'd like to prevent the primary from reporting the secondary as a failover to its incoming connections. Is there any setting that would allow me to do so?